# Unable to verify with minisign

Tags: cryptography

I'm want to install this software and am having trouble with the verification instructions -> https://github.com/alterstep/dnscrypt-osxclient

In particular, when I try

```
minisign -V -P RWRvw8aArS/yEI3In0/zQSb9+qfWonLxjjEYG17cXt6zct6GLKtEvUfk -m dnscrypt-osxclient-*.dmg
```

I simply get,

```
dnscrypt-osxclient-1.0.14.dmg.minisig: No such file or directory
```

Comment: So...presumaby minisign creates the signature in an external file with a .minisig suffix?  Did you sign the collection of files that `dnscrypt-osxclient-*.dmg` expands to before attempting to verify them?

Comment: I figured it out. Dumb question on my part.